# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I used simple jquery method to access data from other url with JSON. But when submit i get a error on the json file. What is that suppose to mean? I get this error. 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```
$.getJSON('http://curvefever.com/achtung/match/16911009/json?callback=?', null, function(data) {
    alert("it worked");
});
```

Comment: It means that isn't actually JSONP.  You can't do that.

Comment: where is the mistake?

Comment: Looks like you're transferring the content as HTML rather than JSON. Change the Content-Type header on the server's endpoint.

Comment: Change from `json?callback=?` to `json?callback=`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: When I changed to json?callback= it gives me this error XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://curvefever.com/achtung/match/16911009/json?callback=. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:81' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Maykonn: That will not help at all.

Comment: So, that means: a) The service hasn't enabled CORS, so you cannot make an Ajax request to it, and b) it doesn't seem to support JSONP. Hence your only option is to route your question through a server which makes the actual request to the service for you.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `callback=?` is telling jQuery to make a request for JSONP.

The server is responding with JSON (but claiming it is HTML).

JSON is not JSONP so trying to "parse" it as such throws an error.

("parse" is in scare quotes because JSONP isn't so much parsed as executed).

---

Get rid of the `callback=?` to try to fetch the data using `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `<script>`. Note, however, that unless you are running the script on `http://curvefever.com`, you will get a cross-origin error since the server is not responding with CORS headers.

Unless you can change the server to return JSONP or to respond with CORS headers, you will need to use a proxy to access the data from client side JavaScript.

Comment: But I have tried by running it with JSONP but I got same problem!

Comment: @user3478007 — What do you mean? The code in the question is already asking for JSONP but that isn't what the server is responding with.

Comment: So I need to fetch the data using XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: As I said in the answer, you need to either (1) change the server to respond with JSONP (2) Use XMLHttpRequest and change the server to respond with CORS headers or (3) use a proxy (which you can set up to work with either JSONP or XHR as you desire)

Comment: _“So I need to fetch the data using XMLHttpRequest?”_ – No, you can’t, because it is not on the same domain, and the remote domain does not indicate explicitly that it wants to grant you access to that data.

Comment: Okey, I don't have lot of knowledge in this, but I can handle json with file but not with url and trying to learn it! Do you have good sited where I can read and learn how to do exactly?

Comment: This one (also Google). There are plenty of keywords to search for in the brief descriptions of the three approaches.